# Windows API seems much faster than BinaryWriter - is my test correct?

Tags: c#, optimization, filestream

[EDIT]

Thanks to @VilleKrumlinde I have fixed a bug that I accidentally introduced earlier when trying to avoid a Code Analysis warning. I was accidentally turning on "overlapped" file handling, which kept resetting the file length. That is now fixed, and you can call `FastWrite()` multiple times for the same stream without issues.

[End Edit]

---

**Overview**

I'm doing some timing tests to compare two different ways of writing arrays of structs to disk. I believe that the perceived wisdom is that I/O costs are so high compared to other things that it isn't worth spending too much time optimising the other things.

However, my timing tests seem to indicate otherwise. Either I'm making a mistake (which is entirely possible), or my optimisation really is quite significant.

**History**

First some history: This `FastWrite()` method was originally written years ago to support writing structs to a file that was consumed by a legacy C++ program, and we are still using it for this purpose. (There's also a corresponding `FastRead()` method.) It was written primarily to make it easier to write arrays of blittable structs to a file, and its speed was a secondary concern.

I've been told by more than one person that optimisations like this aren't really much faster than just using a `BinaryWriter`, so I've finally bitten the bullet and performed some timing tests. The results have surprised me...

It *appears* that my `FastWrite()` method is 30 - 50 times faster than the equivalent using `BinaryWriter`. That seems ridiculous, so I'm posting my code here to see if anyone can find the errors.

**System Specification**

- Tested an x86 RELEASE build, run from OUTSIDE the debugger.
- Running on Windows 8, x64, 16GB memory.
- Run on a normal hard drive (not an SSD).
- Using .Net 4 with Visual Studio 2012 (so .Net 4.5 is installed)

**Results**

My results are:

```
SlowWrite() took 00:00:02.0747141
FastWrite() took 00:00:00.0318139
SlowWrite() took 00:00:01.9205158
FastWrite() took 00:00:00.0327242
SlowWrite() took 00:00:01.9289878
FastWrite() took 00:00:00.0321100
SlowWrite() took 00:00:01.9374454
FastWrite() took 00:00:00.0316074
```

As you can see, that seems to show that the `FastWrite()` is 50 times faster on that run.

Here's my test code. After running the test, I did a binary comparison of the two files to verify that they were indeed identical (i.e. `FastWrite()` and `SlowWrite()` produced identical files).

See what you can make of it. :)

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    internal class Program
    {

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
        struct TestStruct
        {
            public byte   ByteValue;
            public short  ShortValue;
            public int    IntValue;
            public long   LongValue;
            public float  FloatValue;
            public double DoubleValue;
        }

        static void Main()
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\\TEST");
            string filename1 = "C:\\TEST\\TEST1.BIN";
            string filename2 = "C:\\TEST\\TEST2.BIN";

            int count = 1000;
            var array = new TestStruct[10000];

            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; ++i)
                array[i].IntValue = i;

            var sw = new Stopwatch();

            for (int trial = 0; trial < 4; ++trial)
            {
                sw.Restart();

                using (var output = new FileStream(filename1, FileMode.Create))
                using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(output, Encoding.Default, true))
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
                    {
                        output.Position = 0;
                        SlowWrite(writer, array, 0, array.Length);
                    }
                }

                Console.WriteLine("SlowWrite() took " + sw.Elapsed);
                sw.Restart();

                using (var output = new FileStream(filename2, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
                    {
                        output.Position = 0;
                        FastWrite(output, array, 0, array.Length);
                    }
                }

                Console.WriteLine("FastWrite() took " + sw.Elapsed);
            }
        }

        static void SlowWrite(BinaryWriter writer, TestStruct[] array, int offset, int count)
        {
            for (int i = offset; i < offset + count; ++i)
            {
                var item = array[i];  // I also tried just writing from array[i] directly with similar results.
                writer.Write(item.ByteValue);
                writer.Write(item.ShortValue);
                writer.Write(item.IntValue);
                writer.Write(item.LongValue);
                writer.Write(item.FloatValue);
                writer.Write(item.DoubleValue);
            }
        }

        static void FastWrite<T>(FileStream fs, T[] array, int offset, int count) where T: struct
        {
            int sizeOfT = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T));
            GCHandle gcHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(array, GCHandleType.Pinned);

            try
            {
                uint bytesWritten;
                uint bytesToWrite = (uint)(count * sizeOfT);

                if
                (
                    !WriteFile
                    (
                        fs.SafeFileHandle,
                        new IntPtr(gcHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject().ToInt64() + (offset*sizeOfT)),
                        bytesToWrite,
                        out bytesWritten,
                        IntPtr.Zero
                    )
                )
                {
                    throw new IOException("Unable to write file.", new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()));
                }

                Debug.Assert(bytesWritten == bytesToWrite);
            }

            finally
            {
                gcHandle.Free();
            }
        }

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]

        private static extern bool WriteFile
        (
            SafeFileHandle hFile,
            IntPtr         lpBuffer,
            uint           nNumberOfBytesToWrite,
            out uint       lpNumberOfBytesWritten,
            IntPtr         lpOverlapped
        );
    }
}
```

**Follow Up**

I have also tested the code proposed by @ErenErsönmez, as follows (and I verified that all three files are identical at the end of the test):

```
static void ErenWrite<T>(FileStream fs, T[] array, int offset, int count) where T : struct
{
    // Note: This doesn't use 'offset' or 'count', but it could easily be changed to do so,
    // and it doesn't change the results of this particular test program.

    int size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(TestStruct)) * array.Length;
    var bytes = new byte[size];
    GCHandle gcHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(array, GCHandleType.Pinned);

    try
    {
        var ptr = new IntPtr(gcHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject().ToInt64());
        Marshal.Copy(ptr, bytes, 0, size);
        fs.Write(bytes, 0, size);
    }

    finally
    {
        gcHandle.Free();
    }
}
```

I added a test for that code, and at the same time removed the lines `output.Position = 0;` so that the files now grow to 263K (which is a reasonable size).

With those changes, the results are:

**NOTE** Look at how much slower the `FastWrite()` times are when you *don't* keep resetting the file pointer back to zero!:

```
SlowWrite() took 00:00:01.9929327
FastWrite() took 00:00:00.1152534
ErenWrite() took 00:00:00.2185131
SlowWrite() took 00:00:01.8877979
FastWrite() took 00:00:00.2087977
ErenWrite() took 00:00:00.2191266
SlowWrite() took 00:00:01.9279477
FastWrite() took 00:00:00.2096208
ErenWrite() took 00:00:00.2102270
SlowWrite() took 00:00:01.7823760
FastWrite() took 00:00:00.1137891
ErenWrite() took 00:00:00.3028128
```

So it looks like you can achieve almost the same speed using Marshaling *without* having to use the Windows API at all. The only drawback is that Eren's method has to make a copy of the entire array of structs, which could be an issue if memory is limited.

Comment: _Well_, the title would be better? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Comment: What are the results if the first loop calls `FastWrite` and the second loop calls `SlowWrite`?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth It makes no difference, but I wouldn't have expected it to (since I have the outer loop to try to minimise such effects).

Comment: @SonerGönül Yeah, I had problems coming up with a title. Feel free to suggest a better one!

Comment: @MatthewWatson: What if you write `item` directly in `SlowWrite` instead of writing each property individually?

Comment: Try one of the FileStream constructors that allows to specify a buffer size. And set the buffer size to equal the size of output file.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth I get a compile error because there's no overload for `BinaryWriter.Writer(TestStruct item)`. Is there another way I can do it?

Comment: @VilleKrumlinde Done; makes no difference.

Comment: @MatthewWatson my tests show the same...

Comment: To append using WriteFile set overlapped members to 0xFFFFFFFF, according to: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365747%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @VilleKrumlinde Thanks - you've alerted me to my error. My mistake was thinking that overlapped was turned off by passing a default-initialised Overlapped. It wasn't - I need to change to using an IntPtr and pass IntPtr.Zero. I'll update my question! My original code was in fact using IntPtr.Zero, and I changed it to try and avoid a Code Analysis warning. Tisk!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I don't think the difference has to do with `BinaryWriter`. I think it is due to the fact that you're doing multiple file IOs in `SlowWrite` (10000 * 6) vs a single IO in `FastWrite`. Your FastWrite has the advantage of having a single blob of bytes ready to write to the file. On the other hand, you're taking the hit of converting the structs to byte arrays one by one in `SlowWrite`.

To test this theory, I wrote a little method that pre-builds a big byte array of all structs, and then used this byte array in `SlowWrite`:

```
static byte[] bytes;
static void Prep(TestStruct[] array)
{
    int size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(TestStruct)) * array.Length;
    bytes = new byte[size];
    GCHandle gcHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(array, GCHandleType.Pinned);
    var ptr = gcHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject();
    Marshal.Copy(ptr, bytes, 0, size);
    gcHandle.Free();
}

static void SlowWrite(BinaryWriter writer)
{
    writer.Write(bytes);
}
```

Results:

```
SlowWrite() took 00:00:00.0360392
FastWrite() took 00:00:00.0385015
SlowWrite() took 00:00:00.0358703
FastWrite() took 00:00:00.0381371
SlowWrite() took 00:00:00.0373875
FastWrite() took 00:00:00.0367692
SlowWrite() took 00:00:00.0348295
FastWrite() took 00:00:00.0373931
```

Notice that `SlowWrite` now performs very comparable to `FastWrite`, and I think this shows that the performance difference is not due to the actual IO performance but more related to the binary conversion process.

Comment: Yes, I agree with your analysis. Clearly, if you just write an array of bytes it has none of the overhead of pinning the data that the other method has. Anyway, it certainly explains why it's so much faster.

Comment: @SimonMourier good point, added. that's a little helper method I found [here](http://wingerlang.blogspot.com/2011/11/c-struct-to-byte-array-and-back.html).

Comment: But you have to call this Prep method before SlowWrite. This still leaves the question how it's possible that FastWrite without any prepping is so fast.

Comment: @WouterdeKort I think it's simply because the FastWrite() doesn't need to copy *any* memory - it just pins the entire array of structs and passes a pointer to it to the WriteFile() function.

Comment: So that means that there is no way you can achieve that speed from pure managed C#?

Comment: @ErenErsönmez - ok, but I don't know how to get to that performance for SlowWrite with managed code. The best I can do is still 5x slower, which is not *that* surprising, but are you sure of these numbers?

Comment: @WouterdeKort I don't think you can, if you have to either convert the data to a byte array or write each field individually. There's no way I can see to even convert an array of structs to one big byte array (you have to do it a struct at a time).

Comment: @SimonMourier I edited the numbers and removed the phrase faster because I think I had the debugger attached the first time I ran it, so thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: @MatthewWatson I edited the answer to shorten the code for readability, and it now converts the whole array at once (not just one struct at a time). I tested that the resulting byte array is the same as before.

Comment: @ErenErsönmez I have incorporated your results into my question for comparative purposes. Thanks!